# PDF image generating with PHP

Tags: php, image, pdf

I have a PHP application which generates PDF files that may contain images. When generating the PDF file I can't open it because it is corrupted or not PDF format. If I omit the image everything works fine. Long ago this thing worked nicely I don't remember if I changed anything about the handling of images. I use small images so not the imagesize is what causes the problem. Here is my code:

```
if($cell['type'] == "custom_image"){ // Uploaded image
    $imgxploded = explode('.', $cell['img']);
    $imgext = end($imgxploded);
    $imgfile = $root_directory.'uploads/'.$cell['img'];
    $this->Image($imgfile, $blockInternalX, $blockInternalY, $cell['width'], $cell['height'], strtoupper($imgext));
}
```

Any ideas about what goes wrong?

edit: I use FPDF class to manage/produce PDF files

Comment: What's the value returned by strtoupper($imgext) ?

Comment: @NarcisRadu the extension of the image file, in my case strtoupper($imgext) returns 'BMP'

Comment: As far as I remember only JPEG, PNG and GIF are supported.

Comment: Do you output the pdf to browser or save to file? Look at the file in text editor if there are errors from php.

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking if the image path you're generating even exists? that the image embedding call succeeds?

Comment: As I said this thing worked once in the past even with bmp format, but i tried other formats of course with the same result. The PDF is being sent to the browser. And the image path is valid and the image file exists of course